# How can I add an http interceptor to a Quarkus application?

Tags: quarkus

I would like to add an HTTP interceptor to my Quarkus application so I can intercept all HTTP requests. 
How can such that be achieved?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Quarkus uses RESTEasy as its JAX-RS engine. That means that you can take advantage of all of RESTEasy's features, including [Filters and Interceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.0.0.Final/userguide/html/Interceptors.html).

For example to create a very simple security mechanism, all you would need to do is add code like the following:

```java
@Provider
public class SecurityInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        if ("/secret".equals(context.getUriInfo().getPath())) {
          
  context.abortWith(Response.accepted("forbidden!").build());
        }
    }
}
```

It should be noted that this only works for requests that are handled by JAX-RS in Quarkus. If the requests are handled by pure Vert.x or Undertow, the filtering mechanisms of those stacks will need to be used.

**UPDATE**

When using RESTEasy Reactive with Quarkus, the `@ServerRequestFilter` annotation can be used instead of implementing `ContainerRequestFilter`.
See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#request-or-response-filters) for more information

```java
class Filters {

    @ServerRequestFilter(preMatching = true)
    public void preMatchingFilter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        // make sure we don't lose cheese lovers
        if("yes".equals(requestContext.getHeaderString("Cheese"))) {
            requestContext.setRequestUri(URI.create("/cheese"));
        }
    }

    @ServerRequestFilter
    public Optional<RestResponse<Void>> getFilter(ContainerRequestContext ctx) {
        // only allow GET methods for now
        if(ctx.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.GET)) {
            return Optional.of(RestResponse.status(Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd just add that (AFAIK) this will only work for the requests routed to JAX-RS, while you can also have Undertow and Vert.x HTTP endpoints. Those have their own filtering mechanisms.

Comment: @Ladicek can you put some more light on your response?

Comment: what is the difference between `ContainerRequestFilter` and `@ServerRequestFilter` ? Which one will be executed first ?

Comment: They are essentially the same thing, with the annotation form being easier to use

Comment: ContainerRequestFilter dosen't work with Camel REST endpoint, any guess why?